# How to split a list with date, into weekly partition

Tags: python, datetime

I have a csv file with a collection of tweets. I would like to split my collection into weekly partition. All of my tentatives for use the for cycle's terminate with a cycle loop, python works but it don't want to finish. Someone can explain to me which is my error? I have also tried to make a while cycle (while sortr != '') without luck:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import defaultdict

csv1 = open('../archiviato.csv', 'r')
tabula=csv.reader(csv1)
sortr= sorted(tabula)
delta_days = 7
c = 1
months= defaultdict(list)
weeke=defaultdict(list)
weeks = []



for j in sortr:
    tweetID = j[0]
    timestamp = j[2]
    times = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    trmonth = times.month
    trime = times.day
    months[trmonth].append(j)
    for i in sortr:
        tweetID2 = i[0]
        timestamp2 = i[2]
        times2 = datetime.strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        trime2 = times2.day
        if tweetID != tweetID2 and timedelta(trime2 - trime) <= timedelta(days = delta_days):
            if weeks == []:
                a = i,j
                c = 1
                weeks.append(a)
                weeke=[c].append(a)
                print tweetID
                print tweetID2
            else:
                c = 1
                weeke=[c].append(i)
                print tweetID2
        else:
            c+=1
            j = i
            weeks = []
            continue
```

Comment: Can you please specify where the code stays in? If it finishes with error, can you please post the trace?

Comment: My code doesn't finish with an error, but with a loop. It prints all the tweetID numbers and then when they are finished it starts to print another time from the beginning

Comment: You're going trough `sortr` n*n times, so you'll print all the IDs n times

Comment: what is the purpose of `j=i`? `j` is an element, not a counter and reassigning it would not affect the loop

Comment: i want to parse every line of csv with the previous line. My csv is sorted by date. With j=i my new line becomes the previous line for the next iteration

Comment: @Arorodriguezdonaire: I don't understand. Why sortr cycles n times? With for's cycle it should not be run one time for every element of csv? Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't provide a full solution, no csv sample and code snippet is too large. But if you want to "split a list with date, into weekly partition", I would recommend:

Use [date.isocalendar](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) (or [datetime.isocalendar](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isocalendar) in your case) to identify the week. Create a dictionary with `(Year, Week-of-Year)` tuple as keys and the values being lists of tuples of `(timestamp, tweetID)`.

Once you have populated this dictionary and each of the lists, you can sort each list using `elem[1]` (the timestamp, 2nd item in tuple) as the key. To retrieve the full dict, retrieve by:

```
for year_week_tuple in sorted(all_tweets):  # sorts on keys and returns keys
    print 'Year: %d, Week #: %d' % (year_week_tuple[0], year_week_tuple[1])
    for timestamp, tweetID in sorted(all_tweets[year_week_tuple]):
        print 'Tweet time: %s, TweetID: %s' % (timestamp, tweetID)
    print 'End of week'
```

Comment: I don't knew this function, it is my first time with datetime module. It is very useful. Thanks a lot!